# Failing to read USB sectors with int 13h in real mode (assembly 8086)

Tags: assembly, operating-system

First of, hello !

I am trying to make a simple boot loader that boots a trivial OS from a USB (FAT 16) flash drive. But i can't get the int 13h to read "correctly". What i mean by correctly is that it always reads zeroes (i have determined that the read content is indeed 0 the entire length of the buffer by trying to print it out just so i could verify that something is present by using the _print_string procedure ,located below, which doesn't print out anything, i could be incorrect).

The first step is to read the root directory

```
 ;All variables that start with "bpb" or "bs" are part of the Bios Parameter Block

  mov     ax, 488          ; Root directory 
  mov     bx, ds

  mov     es, bx
  mov     bx, si

  mov     cx, 32         ; Read 32 sectors (the entire root directory
  call ReadSectors

 .
 .
 .
 .
```

I determined that the root directory is at sector 488 by simply reading it in a hex editor (i'm not trying to make world class software here... at least for now)

```
 ; PROCEDURE ReadSectors
 ; reads CX sectors from disk starting at AX into
 ;memory location ES:BX

ReadSectors:
 .MAIN:
      mov     di, 0x0005                          ; five retries for error
 .SECTORLOOP:
      push    ax
      push    bx
      push    cx
      call    CHS12
      mov     ah, 0x02                            ; BIOS read sector
      mov     al, 0x01                            ; read one sector
      mov     dl, BYTE [bsDriveNumber]              ; drive
      int     0x13                                ; invoke BIOS
      jnc     .SUCCESS                            ; test for read error
      xor     ax, ax                              ; BIOS reset disk
      int     0x13                                ; invoke BIOS
      dec     di                                  ; decrement error counter
      pop     cx
      pop     bx
      pop     ax
      jnz     .SECTORLOOP                         ; attempt to read again
      int     0x18
 .SUCCESS:

      pop     cx
      pop     bx
      pop     ax
      add     bx, WORD [bpbBytesPerSector]           ; queue next buffer
      inc     ax                                  ; queue next sector
      loop    .MAIN                               ; read next sector

      ret

 ;The procedure expects the LBA in AX
 ;The output is correctly set registers CH,CL,DH for int 13h
 ;I am pretty sure that it doesn't matter which file system is in place for LBA to CHS conversion      

   CHS12:               
    push    bx
    push    ax
    mov     bx, ax                       ; Save LBA
    mov     dx, 0                           
    div     word [bpbSectorsPerTrack]
    add     dl, 01h                      ; Physical sectors begin at 1
    mov     cl, dl                       ; Sectors are being forwarded by CL 
    mov     ax, bx
    mov     dx, 0                        ; Calulate head
    div     word [bpbSectorsPerTrack]
    mov     dx, 0
    div     word [bpbHeadsPerCylinder]
    mov     dh, dl                       ; Head
    mov     ch, al                       ; Cylindar 
    pop     ax
    pop     bx
    mov     dl, byte [bsDriveNumber]        
    ret

;The procoedure expects a pointer to the bufer in SI
_print_string:
    pusha
    mov     ah, 0Eh                     ; BIOS INT 10h teletype (TTY)     
  .Repeat:
    lodsb                               ; Take a character from the string
    cmp     al, 0
    je     .End                        ; if it's zero, its the end of the string
    int     10h                         ; If it's not zero invoke the BIOS
    jmp    .Repeat                   ; and go to the next character
 .End:
    popa
    ret
```

The process with which i got this .bin code is pretty ugly. I combined this code (which can be at most 446 bytes long due to the 447-512 being the partitioning table and the boot signature) with the partitioning table and the boot signature and written it directly into the 1st sector of my USB, with a small C program.

EDIT1:

```
;                 Interupt vector table               0000                          
;                 -------------------------------                               
;                 BIOS Data Area                      0040                          
;                 -------------------------------                              
;                 PrtScr Status / Unused              0050                          
;                 -------------------------------
;                 Boot sector                         07C0                          
;                 -------------------------------                               
;                 Bafer 8KB                           07E0                         
;                 -------------------------------                              
;                 Boot stack 16KB                      09E0              
;                 -------------------------------                              
;                 Segment where the kernel is loaded    2000  (ImageLoadSeg)                  
;                 -------------------------------       <- OS aplications are loaded 2800 
;                Unused                    3000  do A000     28 KB             
;                 -------------------------------                                                         
;                                                  A000
```

Comment: This code shouldn't be in a MBR, it should be in the volume boot record (VBR). There's no BPB in the MBR and there's no partition table in the VBR. The MBR just loads and runs the VBR of the active partition. The VBR loads the next boot stage from the file system in the partition. Also make sure you're not hard coding the drive number. The value in `bsDriveNumber` should be the value in DL when your boot sector started.

Comment: This really isn't a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Secondly you have tagged this as 8086 yet I see `pusha`/`popa` which wasn't available until the 80186/80188.

Comment: Apologies for not meeting the  requirement for this post. So i need to write this code to the first sector of the active partition ?

Comment: @vuk: If it's a boot loader write it to 1st sector of active partition (and find/install an MBR that will chainload it). If its an MBR you should only be loading 1 sector. Also note that you're probably going to want to use `int 0x13, ah = 0x42` to read from the device, rather than the old/limited CHS function.

Comment: @Brendan Ok , but if i write it to the 1st sector, won't the MBR need to read the 1st sector of the disk to relocate it into main memory, and then we come back to the original problem? (sorry if this question is a bit newbie-ish i'm barely a few months in this boot loading business)

Comment: If you were to show all your code, and the commands you use to build the image it would help. It is a hit and miss thing with this question because it could be many things, and likely not in the code shown.

Comment: @MichaelPetch What this code is supposed to do is set up the stack,DS and everything in the EDIT1. Then it reads the root directory to find the kernel.bin and loads it into memory and jumps to the 1st instruction in it.